# Trouble with deploy django channels using Daphne and Nginx

Tags: django, nginx, django-channels, nginx-config, daphne

I got a 502 error when I'm trying to open a website. I used the instructions from the official website  [link](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploying.html)

Added new file lifeline.conf at **/etc/supervisor/conf.d/**

**lifeline.conf**

```
[fcgi-program:asgi]
# TCP socket used by Nginx backend upstream
socket=tcp://localhost:8000

# Directory where your site's project files are located
directory=/home/ubuntu/lifeline/lifeline-backend

# Each process needs to have a separate socket file, so we use process_num
# Make sure to update "mysite.asgi" to match your project name
command=/home/ubuntu/Env/lifeline/bin/daphne -u /run/daphne/daphne%(process_num)d.sock --fd 0 --access-log - --proxy-head$

# Number of processes to startup, roughly the number of CPUs you have
numprocs=4

# Give each process a unique name so they can be told apart
process_name=asgi%(process_num)d

# Automatically start and recover processes
autostart=true
autorestart=true

# Choose where you want your log to go
stdout_logfile=/home/ubuntu/asgi.log
redirect_stderr=true
```

Setup nginx conf

```
upstream channels-backend {
    server localhost:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name staging.mysite.com www.staging.mysite.com;
    client_max_body_size 30M;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
        proxy_pass http://channels-backend;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
}
```

I checked the asgi log file and it contains an error .

```
daphne: error: the following arguments are required: application
```

I'm guessing a mistake in **lifeline.conf**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are not passing asgi application to daphne, because configuration you pasted in question has missing line. You have to pass it correctly. Assuming you have conf `package` with `asgi.py` module inside it containing asgi application instance, you have to do

```
command=/home/ubuntu/Env/lifeline/bin/daphne -u /run/daphne/daphne%(process_num)d.sock conf.asgi:application
```

`conf.asgi:application` should be at the end.

Comment: thank you for you advice. After update I got new error `2019-08-09 11:36:23,711 INFO     Starting server at unix:/run/daphne/daphne0.sock
2019-08-09 11:36:23,714 INFO     HTTP/2 support not enabled (install the http2 and tls Twisted extras)
2019-08-09 11:36:23,714 INFO     Configuring endpoint unix:/run/daphne/daphne0.sock
2019-08-09 11:36:23,720 CRITICAL Listen failure: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '2843' -> b'/run/daphne/daphne0.sock.lock'`

Comment: Also I cant find folder daphne at /run/

Comment: I create `daphne` folder in /run/, then everything work well